# Restrict access to safe mode in the Android 6.0+ devices without rooting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, safe-mode, kiosk-mode

I locked down my device (running `Android 6.0`+) so that only my application can run on it. I have to give these devices to the employees in my firm. Now I have implemented an Enterprise Mobility Management(EMM) solution to run only one application. But I'm afraid the employees still have access to Safe Mode through which they can uninstall my company app and get access to the entire device.

So I have come across various third party Kiosk Applications like Mobilock Pro who gives the functionality to restrict safe mode without rooting. The link to their Blog is [here](http://blog.mobilock.in/2016/07/20/restrict-safe-mode-access-android-devices/). Android has itself posted [here](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#locktask) that this restriction is possible with Marshmallow.

I have searched for similar questions but None of them used Marshmallow APIs.

So my question is how can I implement this restricted access of safe mode on my own? Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My solution which I applied is to simply deactivate the volume down & so they will be unable to go into the safe mode, this is very practical and you will be saving money.

Comment: By "simply deactivate the volume down", did you mean physically break it? Otherwise, could you explain how to do it?